# Creating a new column based on conditions of first and last value of groupby Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, conditional-statements

I have a pandas dataframe and would like to create a new column with values based on conditions from the first and last row of a groupby. The conditions required are

mgr to mgr = hired as mgr

emp to mgr = promoted to mgr

emp to emp = hired as emp

mgr to emp = status change

```
date        email          level 
01/01/2000  john@abc.com   mgr
05/06/2000  john@abc.com   mgr     
10/01/2001  john@abc.com   mgr     
14/02/2000  kimdo@abc.com  emp     
19/10/2001  kimdo@abc.com  mgr     
12/05/2000  waint@abc.com  emp  
08/08/2000  waint@abc.com  emp  
14/04/2001  waint@abc.com  emp     
22/05/2000  neds@abc.com   mgr
08/11/2000  neds@abc.com   mgr     
12/06/2001  neds@abc.com   emp
```

Would like to achieve the results below

```
date        email          level   status
01/01/2000  john@abc.com   mgr     hired as mgr
10/01/2001  john@abc.com   mgr     hired as mgr
14/02/2000  kimdo@abc.com  emp     promoted to mgr
19/10/2001  kimdo@abc.com  mgr     promoted to mgr
12/05/2000  waint@abc.com  emp     hired as emp
14/04/2001  waint@abc.com  emp     hired as emp
22/05/2000  neds@abc.com   mgr     status change
12/06/2001  neds@abc.com   emp     status change
```

So far, am able to select the first and last rows of the dataframe based on a groupyby, but am not entirely sure how to apply the conditions to get the new 'status' column. Appreciate any form of help, thank you.

```
df2 = df.groupby('email', as_index=False).nth([0,-1])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df2 = df.groupby('email', as_index=False).nth([0,-1])
```

You can try:

```
d={'mgr:mgr':'hired as mgr','emp:mgr':'promoted to mgr','emp:emp':'hired as emp','mgr:emp':'status change'}
#created a dict for mapping
```

Finally:

```
df2.loc[:,'status']=df2.groupby('email')['level'].transform(':'.join).map(d)
```

output of `df2`:

```
    date        email           level   status
0   01/01/2000  john@abc.com    mgr     hired as mgr
2   10/01/2001  john@abc.com    mgr     hired as mgr
3   14/02/2000  kimdo@abc.com   emp     promoted to mgr
4   19/10/2001  kimdo@abc.com   mgr     promoted to mgr
5   12/05/2000  waint@abc.com   emp     hired as emp
7   14/04/2001  waint@abc.com   emp     hired as emp
8   22/05/2000  neds@abc.com    mgr     status change
10  12/06/2001  neds@abc.com    emp     status change
```

Answer (score 1):

try creating a `map` `dictionary` to map the status.

```
fl = lambda s: s.iloc[[0,-1]]
d = {'mgr-mgr': 'hired as mgr', 'emp-mgr': 'promoted to mgr', 'emp-emp': 'hired as emp', 'mgr-emp': 'status change'}
res = df.groupby('email', as_index=False)['level'].apply(lambda x: (fl(x).shift(1) + "-" + (fl(x))).bfill()).map(d)
res.index= res.index.droplevel()
df['status'] = res
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

---

|  | date | email | level | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01/01/2000 | john@abc.com | mgr | hired as mgr |
| 2 | 10/01/2001 | john@abc.com | mgr | hired as mgr |
| 3 | 14/02/2000 | kimdo@abc.com | emp | promoted to mgr |
| 4 | 19/10/2001 | kimdo@abc.com | mgr | promoted to mgr |
| 5 | 12/05/2000 | waint@abc.com | emp | hired as emp |
| 7 | 14/04/2001 | waint@abc.com | emp | hired as emp |
| 8 | 22/05/2000 | neds@abc.com | mgr | status change |
| 10 | 12/06/2001 | neds@abc.com | emp | status change |

Comment: seem to be getting all nans in the 'res' object that was created

Comment: @wjie08: are you using the same dataframe?